# java - general synchronizedList question

Tags: java, synchronized

I have a general question regarding synchronized List.
Lets say that in the constructor I am createing a list

```
List synchronizedList = Collections.synchronizedList(list);
```

and I have one method adds an object to the list.

```
public void add(String s){ 
    synchronizedList.add(s)
}
```

There is another thread that checks every few seconds if there are a few rows , dump it to a file and deletes them all.

Now lets say I iterate each row and save it to the db. 
after all iteration I clear the list.

How does the multithread support help me?
I could add an element to the list just before the clear() in the other thread occurs .
Unless I  manage the lock myself (which I dont realy need a synched list for that ) it myself.

Comment: As all the three answers state, synchronized list means that all the operations on that list are guaranteed to be atomic or guarantee serial access to individual method calls. I had to ask my colleague what is that mean. So it means operations on List like(from above code snippet) `synchronizedList.size()` and `synchronizedList.add(s)` cannot be in parallel. This is not obvious for some people who is reading this thread. So though of adding to help other who dont understand. Thanks @WhiteFang34, @jb-nizet and @khachik for explanations below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The synchronized list returned by `Collections` won't help in your case. It's only good if you need to guarantee serial access to individual method calls. If you need to synchronize around a larger set of operations, then you need to manually wrap that code in a `synchronized` block. The [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) states:

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned list when iterating over it.

If your list is used elsewhere you can at least safeguard it from individual method calls that would otherwise not be thread-safe. If you're entirely managing the list however, you can just add a `synchronized` block to your `add` method and use the same lock that you'll use when iterating over it.

Answer (score 13):

`synchronizedList` indeed only guarantees that every method call on the list is synchronized. If you need multiple operations to be done in a synchronized way, you have to handle the synchronization yourself.

BTW, this is explicitely said in the [javadoc for Collections.synchronizedList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) :

> It is imperative that the user
>   manually synchronize on the returned
>   list when iterating over it:

```
  List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
      ...
  synchronized(list) {
      Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
      while (i.hasNext())
          foo(i.next());
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

synchronized list means that all the operations on that list are guaranteed to be atomic. The scenario you describe requires to have some locking outside the list. Consider semaphores or making `synchronized` block to implement monitors. Take a look at [java.util.concurrent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).